# Capture list from autocomplete drop down

Tags: testing, cucumber, watir

I am trying to capture list from this drop down.

```
<input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="typeaheadDataPlain" autocomplete="off" class="clear-btn-input gcw-storeable text gcw-origin gcw-required gcw-distinct-locations " data-gcw-field-type="origin" data-gcw-storeable-name="gcw-origin" data-js-theme="autocomplete" data-lob="FLIGHTS" data-locale="en_US" data-mask="95" data-minchar="1" data-provide="utypeahead" data-template="hbs/templates/destinationCustom" data-tooltip-id="typeaheadDataPlain" data-version="v4" data-airport_code_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-airport_code" data-hotel_id_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-hotel_id" data-lat_long_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-lat_long" data-region_id_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-region_id" data-region_type_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-region_type" data-station_code_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-station_code" data-city_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-city" data-country_code_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-country_code" data-category_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-category" data-heds_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-heds" data-search_name_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-search_name" data-ta_element="flight-origin-hp-flight-ta" id="flight-origin-hp-flight" placeholder="City or airport" spellcheck="false" type="text">
```

but I can't find no "ul" and I don't know where it's getting the list from. This is what I see when the list appears in HTML.

```
<div class="autocomplete-dropdown" style="left: -2px; max-width: 604px; min-width: 286px; width: 604px; display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: How you are trying to capture this autocomplete list, are you using selenium or any other tool ?

Comment: This person is using Watir, which uses Selenium.

Comment: The first element is a text field, not a drop down. It looks like the second element is a div that likely is using fancy javascript / css to act like a drop down. The values of the drop down are likely in another element on the DOM.

Comment: When you checked the HTML was the dropdown displayed? I have seen some pages that didn't load the list of items until the dropdown was displayed - eg they were doing asynchronous calls to get the data based on the typed value.

Comment: I am pretty new to software testing field. in this, I have to capture the list items which populate once we start typing in the text box. in other examples we can see 'ul' or 'list' but in this, I am unable to find any of those in HTML.